# Google maps/places API search by phone

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

We have a signup page where the user enters his business phone number. We want to find his business information from the phone number for verification. How can this be done with Google places/maps api? Is there any better alternative? I am kind of lost.

Comment: if you found some concrete solution then it'd be better to share on this plateform

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55027347/790464

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the google api to double-check, their response doesn't return a phone number for the company either. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/

It also may depend on the type of business you're looking for but Yelp does allow phone number searches in their API:
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/phone_search

Comment: please dear , stick to the point . question is not about yelp . It clearly states "how can we get a place using phone number in google places api"

Comment: Question also clearly states: "Is there any better alternative?". Please appreciate out-of-the-box suggestions even if they may not be directly applicable to your situation.

Comment: @ImranNaqvi calm down man, you're not even the person who asked the question

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica i'm fine dear , no worries

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can get what you want using the [Place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) call of the web-service api.  Amongst the fields returned are the `formatted_phone_number` and `international_phone_number`.

Comment: yeah josh we can get phone number , but what the question says is "how can we get the place using the phone number"

Comment: Sorry, need to read better.  Have you tried running a [text search request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) for the phone number in question and parsing the results?  It's definitely a kludge solution, but it might work.

Comment: @JoshDoebbert just tried it, doesn't work I'm afraid. It returns `"status": "ZERO_RESULTS"`